# adding user defined libraries to SVN

Tags: java, svn, libraries

I am developing a project for which I have used a number of external libraries (in jar format). I have added all of the external jars I have downloaded and added to the build path to our version control (subversion) as well.

However it has recently come to my attention that a number of the libraries are not in the SVN tree. I have looked into it a bit, and these are the libraries that I have created as user defined libraries and added to the build path in that way, following the instructions on the respective web pages. When I right click on them in Eclipse, I don't see the options to add them to the version control. So I decided to export them to the lib folder I have on the SVN tree. I am not sure if it's the right way of solving this problem, would appreciate som help on the matter.

I am not sure if it's of any help but the packages in question are: Commons Math, JFreeChart and JCommons.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using something like Maven or Ivy for your external dependencies?

Comment: thanks for the tips but I am not sure if they have anything to do with my situation, or well I guess I am not sure if I understand what those are good for to start with. Perhaps I haven't really made my question clear enough.. I have an eclipse project which I have included a number of libraries for external resources, a number of them are set-up as "user libraries" instead of the usual way of adding "external jar files" to the build path. Which, I think, results in them not being added to the version tracking.